# why is on() not working?

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to simply use the .on('click') event, as I'm creating elements dynamically on my page.

testing the event and its just not firing:

```
function showSub(){
    alert('wefef');
}

$('.common-main-row').on('click', showSub);
```

and in actual fact, in this example, .common-main-row is always on the page and not created dynamically

Comment: Does your code run after the DOM is ready? (Note - when you want to use `.on()` with elements that are created dynamically you will have to delegate the event handler to an ancestor element).

Comment: it does, yes using $(document).ready(function(){});

Comment: Before `$('.common-main-row').on('click', showSub);` log the result of the query somehow, just to make sure you're really attaching the event. Probably you're running the javascript before the DOM is ready. For example, if you have a console, try: `console.log($('.common-main-row').length)`

Comment: @rpsep2 - In addition to fog's suggestion, check the console for any existing errors. What version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: what is the html code of the element with the class `common-main-row` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What version of jQuery are you using, on() is only available in jQuery since 1.7, before that it was live(). Try this.

http://jsfiddle.net/Upvfx/1/

```
function showSub(){
    alert('wefef');
}

$('.common-main-row').live('click', showSub);
```

EDIT:

I used jQuery 1.8.3 in the jsfiddle example. on() is included in jQuery since 1.7. 
http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: first to answer with basically telling me to update my jquery, thanks

Comment: @rpsep2 Pro tip: keep the JavaScript error console open. Seeing error messages helps debugging quite a lot.

Comment: Ok, apparently on() has been around since 1.7, that's for pointing that out @JamesAllardice, editing my answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the lastest jQuery version, that your code is wrapped in

```
 $(document).ready(function(){ /* your code here */ });
```

Place this in your header.

```
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/sEfuu/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.common-main-row').click( function(e){
        //do stuff
        alert('wefef');
    });
});
```

Comment: This just calls `.on()` internally anyway. It will not make any difference.

Answer (score 0):

You can use .bind()

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mRuTb/)**

```
function showSub(){
    alert('wefef');
}

$('.common-main-row').bind('click', showSub);
```

Comment: `.bind()` just calls `.on()` internally. This won't make any difference.